# Does C++ have no pointer type?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

In C++, these two have no difference.

```
char *pC;
char* pC2;
```

I thought that the type **char** and **char*** have got to be different types and all the C++ programmers had to use this form **char* p** instead of **char *p**, because when you do **char *p** it doesn't seem to specify that the programmer is using a pointer to char.

However, when you take a look at this code below, which is the same as nullptr from C++0x, it seems that T doesn't recognize any pointer type.

```
const class{
public:
    // T is char, not char* in this case.
    // T* is char*, but I thought it would be char**
    template <class T>
    operator T*() const{   
        cout << "Operator T*() Called" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    template <class C, class T> 
    operator T C::*() const{
        cout << "Operator C T::*() Called" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

private:
    void operator&() const;
}AAA = {};

int main(){
 // operator T*() const is called, 
 // but it's awkward,
 // because it looks like T will be char* type, so T* will be char**
    char* pC = AAA;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question title is nonsense. Obviously C++ has pointer types, and you know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that `char` and `char*` are different types. Whether programmers say `char* p` or `char *p` is irrelevant. Those are three separate tokens, and there can be as many or as few spaces between them as you want; it has no effect on the type of `p`.

When you initialize `pC` with `AAA`, the compiler needs to choose a conversion operator from `AAA`. Since it's initializing a `char*` variable, it wants `operator char*`. To make that work, the compiler needs to choose `T = char`. Since `T` is `char`, there's no way `T*` could be `char**`.

If you want `T` to be a pointer type, then use `AAA` in a context where a pointer-to-pointer type is expected, such as `char**`. Then `T` will be `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `char* p` or `char *p` is just the same thing, both are pointers to a `char`.